# How to take backup in IIS

Tags: iis-7, backup

How do I take a backup of a site (and its settings) in IIS7 so that later if something goes wrong I can go back to my previous settings?

**Updated:**

I just want the settings, main website/sub- application, application pool etc. I can restore code from svn.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add backup "backup_name"
```

The above basically backs up `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`

You can also look into application config history: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/129/using-iis-70-configuration-history/

Comment: I keep coming here and I inevitably go [here](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration) next. For everyone's future reference.

Comment: Thanks @Brad.. that was the next thing I would go for!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start with (assuming a normal installation)

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

as that's where the IIS config file is for websites.

There's not really the same "backup this site" like there was in IIS6, since they redid the underlying model.

Comment: You should really backup the whole config folder. It's entirely possible for there be changes to `administration.config` and custom schema additions as well.

Comment: @Kev notice my "start with" on account of I firmly believe that until you understand what IIS is doing, asking it to backup is useless. You have to understand the model in IIS6 where it uses the metabase*, and  understand in IIS7 there is no similar metabase.  ~ *as in the metabase could be corrupted when you do a backup so it won't help to make a backup ;)